# C# Can't get combobox Selected Item string

Tags: c#, combobox

I have i problem with a combobox value. The `name` string variable return nothing, but when I check (name != ""), return true.

```
    private void ReftreshComboBox()
            {
                comboBoxAlbums.Items.Clear();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in mysql.GetAlbums())
                {
                    comboBoxAlbums.Items.Add(kvp.Value.ToString());
                }
            }
    this.name = comboBoxAlbums.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: Maybe it's something you cannot see? A space, tab or other kind of whitespace?

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting a Null Reference Exception, because it seems you don't have any selected items.

Comment: i think that last line is at a different location in his code

Comment: No, I select item from ComboBox, and check it by MessageBox. Return empty box

Comment: @IAbstract i trying this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.name = comboBoxAlbums.GetItemText(comboBoxAlbums.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: Then like h4xpace said, either nothing is selected or the field list item is empty.

Comment: but I have selected a item from combobox, then checked it by Messagebox but te box was empty... I have tried all of methods. Result = nothing.

Comment: Ok, this method work. The problem was with name... stupid situation. All works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.name) and I bet you will find your answer. string is a reference type. Its nullable.

That is: null != ""